# Printf arguments not pushed on the stack

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, stack, push

I'm in the process of trying to understand the stack mechanisms.

From the theory I have seen, before a function is called, its arguments are pushed onto the stack.

However when calling printf in the code below, none of them are pushed:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    char *s = " test string";
    printf("Print this: %s and this %s \n", s, s);
    return 1;
}
```

I've put a break in gdb to the printf instruction, and when displaying the stack, none of the 3 arguments are pushed onto the stack.

The only thing pushed to the stack is the string address s as can be seen in the disassembled code below:

```
   0x000000000040052c <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040052d <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400530 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000400534 <+8>: movq   $0x400604,-0x8(%rbp) // variable pushed on the stack
   0x000000000040053c <+16>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
   0x0000000000400540 <+20>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400544 <+24>:    mov    %rax,%rsi
   0x0000000000400547 <+27>:    mov    $0x400611,%edi
   0x000000000040054c <+32>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400551 <+37>:    callq  0x400410 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000400556 <+42>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x000000000040055b <+47>:    leaveq
```

Actually, the only argument appearing so far in the disassembled code is when "Print this: %s and this %s \n" is put in %edi...

```
   0x0000000000400547 <+27>:    mov    $0x400611,%edi
```

SO my question is: **why am i not seeing 3 push instructions for each of my three arguments ?**

uname -a:
3.8.0-31-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 20:03:44 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 4):

On 64 bits Linux x86-64 systems, the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi-0.99.pdf) (x86-64 [Application Binary Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)) does not push arguments on stack, but uses some registers (this [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) is slightly faster).

<sup>If you pass many arguments -e.g. a dozen- some of them gets pushed on the stack.</sup>

Perhaps read first the wikipage on [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) before reading the x86-64 ABI specifications.

<sup>For variadic functions like `printf` details are a bit scary.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your compiler, you will need to allocate space on the heap for your pointer 's'.
Instead of
`char *s;`
use
`char s[300];`
to allocate 300 bytes of room
Otherwise 's' is simply pointing up the stack - which can be random

This could be partly why you are not seeing PUSH instructions.

Also, I don't see why there should be a PUSH instruction for the pointers required in printf? The assembler is simply copying (MOV) the value of the pointers

Comment: No, it is a matter of ABI how arguments are passed. Declaring a 300 bytes local string would only affect the first instructions (setting the call frame), not the way arguments are passed.

Comment: Yes you're right Basile. I should have focused more on the compiler (ABI) for the printf function.